# Show multiple labels on kendoUI chart category axis

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

Is there any possibility of showing more than one label in the category axis?
I need to show two fields from my data source in my category axis(And,yes there is no multi category axis. I need to show multiple fields on the same category axis. Please help if I'm missing out searching for any related topic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried yet.

Comment: categoryAxis: {
                    field: "year",
                    labels: {
                        rotation: -90
                    }
                },

Sorry for not putting whole code. I am new to this stack over flow,couldnt comment whole code. I just need to get another field in this category axis. named , 'Group' like that of year, and both should be visible in the category axis.

Comment: You can use label templates in the category axis: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/etoNO

Comment: @ezanker thanks alot. That helped me a bit of it. But the dates aren't in the format like \n in the datasource. So i would like to split the date and use the hours and mins in the next line. I hope u understood. Thanks for this though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use label templates on the categoryAxis labels:

```
    categoryAxis: {
      field: 'submitTime',
      majorGridLines: {
        visible: false
      },
      labels: {
         visible: true,
          template: ' #= FormatLabel(dataItem) # '
        }
    },
```

In this example the template is passing the dataItem to a function which builds the desired string:

```
function FormatLabel(dataItem){
  var tg = dataItem.TargetGroup;
  var st = dataItem.submitTime.replace(" ", "\n");
  return tg + "\n" + st;      
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/etoNO)**

Answer (score 0):

In your series, you can define the template on the label to display pretty much anything you want from the item it is bound to.

```
series: [ 
      { 
        field: 'totalVisits', 
        name: 'Total Visits',  
        labels: {
          visible: true,
          template: ' #= dataItem.month # \n Total Visits : #= dataItem.totalVisits # \n Unique Visitors : #= dataItem.uniqueVisitors # '
        }
      }
    ],
```

See working sample at [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EhuBO)

If you need a bit more functionality, you can set that template to a function, and return whatever you want from it.

```
series: [ 
      { 
        field: 'totalVisits', 
        name: 'Total Visits',  
        labels: {
          visible: true,
          template: chartSeriesTemplate
        }
      }
   ],

function chartSeriesTemplate(e) {
      return kendo.format("{0} \n Total Visits:{1}\n Unique Visitors:{2} \n Ratio :{3}", e.dataItem.month, e.dataItem.totalVisits, e.dataItem.uniqueVisitors, (parseInt(e.dataItem.uniqueVisitors) / parseInt(e.dataItem.totalVisits)).toFixed(2));
    }
```

See working sample at [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/inEqe)

Documentation for series template at [Kendo Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.labels.template)

Comment: I'm afraid thats not what i meant. I already proposed my team in using series label template. But they need multiple labels in the category axis.
Here is the image of how they need. <http://i.imgur.com/kcTM7Hi.png> 'All meters' is the value of one of the field and date is another field. I need to display both. I hope you understand the problem.
Thanks :)

Comment: Gitner sorry for not tagging