# kendoui chart - grouping and category label in the category axis

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

is it possible to have a label for the category and a label for the grouping on the category axis of a kendo column chart

this is a working dojo
https://dojo.telerik.com/EhahiriK/2

this is what i'd like to achieve
[image]

i've found this discussion that partially solve this problem (multiple labels on the categoryAxis) but here the labels are neither related nor aligned to the bars
[Show multiple labels on kendoUI chart category axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541233/show-multiple-labels-on-kendoui-chart-category-axis)